# Can't get correct elapsed time

Tags: javascript, date, timer, webgl

I'm trying to make a timer in JavaScript for animating in WebGL. This is the code that gets the elapsed time using the Date class.

```
var lastTime = Date.now();
var elapsed = 0;
var timeNow = Date.now();
function animate() {
    timeNow = Date.now();
    if(timeNow > lastTime) {
        elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;
        console.log(elapsed);
    }

    lastTime = timeNow;
}
```

Animate is called from a window.requestAnimationFrame() callback. But that seems to be generating a value between 16 and 17. It never goes above 20. Whats going on?

EDIT: Actually, that was my derp. Elapsed needed to be += not =. Thanks Abstract Algorithm for explaining why it was between 16 and 17. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `animate` 60 times per second, because that's probably what you set in `requestAnimationFrame` (and is set by default). 1000 ms / 60 frames = 16.xx ms.
So animation is called every ~16ms and that's what you're getting.

```
if ( !window.requestAnimationFrame ) {

window.requestAnimationFrame = ( function() {

    return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function( /* function FrameRequestCallback */ callback, /* DOMElement Element */ element ) {

        window.setTimeout( callback, 1000 / 60 );   // so call it every ~16ms

    };

} )();
```

}

Comment: Edited answer. You can see how to change the `requestAnimFrame`. This function is widely used for animation and 60fps is "standard".

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But I want the total elapsed time it has run.

Comment: Oh wow uh, nevermind. I forgot a += on elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;